# jquery equivalent to window.innerHeight

Tags: jquery

What is the jquery equivalent to window.innerHeight

I tried

```
$(window).innerHeight()
```

and

```
$(window).height()
```

but both did not give me the values I wanted. They returned null;

Comment: Select the `window` object. Not a `window` element. It's not a string.. `$(window).height()`. Also.. you've already asked like 4 of these questions. "What the jQuery equivalent of X..".. really?

Answer (score 3):

If you wrap `window` in quotes, Jquery will look for an HTML element(eg: `a` tag `$('a')`.

Since `window` is an object, remove the quotes and it'll work.

`$(window).innerHeight()`

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to access the `window` object by using a string.

Simply using `$(window).height()` will work.

As read in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/innerheight/), `innerHeight` includes padding but doesn't include borders, while `height` excludes padding too ( jquery [Height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) )

Comment: is it innerHeight() or height()?